# Custom error pages based on path/url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

Is it possible to have a custom error page based on URL or path?  For example, I want any 404 errors that happen under /images, /styles, /javascript to fail very fast with a standard 404 not found.  However, anything else should generate a user-friendly custom 404 (which may be a little heavier response, being a user-friendly page with normal page layout elements).  Is this possible?  Right now I am using something like this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

But this captures *all* 404 errors.

Comment: Consider use your-own recognising of errors in Application_Error() method. For example, you can check the route - if error-causing request url contains "/images" or "/styles" or "/javascript", redirect to the simple 404 page; in other cases you'd redirect users to another one page.<br/>P.S. Look at this link: http://www.secretgeek.net/custom_errors_mvc.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a .config based solution to this problem, but what I am ended up doing is the following:

- I kept my `<httpErrors>` configuration, which redirected to /Error/NotFound
- Inside `/Error/NotFound`, I watch for my exclusion conditions and render a "basic" version of my error page, that is minimal and light, avoiding layouts, etc.

  ```
  public ViewResult NotFound()
  {
      if(testForFastFail){
          return View("NotFoundBasic");
      }

      return View();
  }
  ```